# How to remove the 25MB file size limit on PNG desktop wallpaper for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, desktop, desktop-customization

I recently purchased a new 40 inch, 4k monitor which has been great. However, in my hunt to find high resolution, high quality desktop wallpapers for my new desktop size, I have found that I'm unable to apply any PNG wallpaper larger than 24.9MB (or effectively 25MB). It seems to be a hard limit for PNGs (JPEG doesn't seem to have the same problem) and whenever I try to set a wallpaper that's larger than that, it thinks for a second or two and then automatically sets the background to a solid color.

One solution would be to manually reformat and compress or resize the images in Photoshop. But I have quite a few images that are all different ratios and sizes and that seems to be more work than is necessary. Work smarter, not harder, right?

So my question boils down to this:
Is there a way to remove this file size limit for desktop wallpapers in Windows 10 through a registry hack or setting? Or is this something that's hard-coded into the OS?

I Googled my problem and it didn't yield any relevant results that I could see. So, hopefully this means this isn't a duplicate question.

Spec info that might be helpful, but probably isn't: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit ver. 1607, Dell T7500 Workstation, Duel Xeon X5650 Processors, 48GB of DDR3 RAM, EVGA GeForce GTX 970 4GB.

Comment: You should first update to Version 1607.

Comment: [https://tinypng.com/](https://tinypng.com/) - Compress bulk images with various dimensions. No quality loss. You may test if it suits your need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated Windows this morning to 1607 and it still has the same problem. I updated my question to reflect that. Also, the tinypng.com site only allows PNGs of 5MB or less which doesn't work here since the ones that I need to convert are 25MB+.

Comment: I know this is a longshot but have you tried saving the PNG for web in PhotoShop or similar, it may bring you under the 25MB limit.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure this is "hard limit", which you cannot just modify.
But, PNG files can be compressed, "crunched" without quality loss.

- https://pnggauntlet.com/
- http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/
- https://trimage.org/

These are all free. Feel free to try them all.
**IrfanView** can also save PNG using different *compression*, but I am sure the tools I listed above also compress the PNG.